# Cmake unable to locate Boost Libraries (Windows)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, messagebroker, cmake-gui

I'm currently trying to build the Apache qpid messaging broker on Windows using CMake and the Boost (C++). I went through the initial steps of setting up Qpid on Windows as specified in [this file](https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/1382a5125fd52e87268a83d28db4b5e9). I set the variable `BOOST_ROOT` to "C:/< Home >/Downloads/boost_1_61_0" initially so that CMake could find the Boost Libraries (e.g. random, math, chrono, etc.) but I got [this log](https://gist.github.com/loremIpsum1771/fc1d912bbe5a741325cdd259f7a53837) saying that it could only find some of the libraries, but not others. I thought that maybe the filepath needed to include the directory where the Boost libraries were actually located (i.e. C:/< Home >/Downloads/boost_1_61_0/boost) but I was unable to reset the `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable despite deleting it and creating another one.

I was advised on [this forum](http://qpid.2158936.n2.nabble.com/Issue-when-using-CMake-to-install-Qpid-broker-td7646766.html#a7646949) to delete the cache file for CMake using the GUI so I could reset the variable, but that didn't seem to work either.

Am I using the correct file path for `BOOST_ROOT`? If not, how should I go about changing it?

Comment: All the libraries you couldn't find have binary components.  Do you have Boost .lib / .dll files for your particular toolchain / build generator?

Comment: ***to delete the cache file for CMake using the GUI so I could reset the variable, but that didn't seem to work either.*** You could have just reset the value in the GUI. Did you compile boost? Since you are using the most recent boost do you have a recent CMake binary (I am not sure what version will recognize 1.61)? If your CMake does not know about boost-1.61 you can override that with `set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.61" "1.61.0")` before the find_package(boost ...)

Comment: No I didn't compile boost initially, I'm doing the steps in section 5.2.1 [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) for the compilation. For step 3, I'm supposed to run `b2 install` in the directory where Boost.Build should be installed. I'm assuming that this should be boost_1_61_0\tools\build ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the Boost libraries (e.g. [chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/chrono.html)) need to be compiled first. If you have only downloaded Boost library from the website, you probably have not built these libraries. [Check Boost website for instructions how to build on Windows.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) The site also lists which libraries need to be built. Alternatively, you can search for sites where pre-built Boost libraries are hosted. You can download and install from there.